# Django, form.is_valid() What does it check?

Tags: python, django

I do not use the form of models.form
I received and stored each items of request.POST and request.FILES
I will make my validation function.
So I wonder what validation it does. (ex. input is empty, etc.)

Comment: you can read the django docs about validation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: It does not only validate: it also *cleans* data. For example converting the string `'2022-07-30'` to a datetime object. All formats are tried in the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` setting, which will thus try to parse more than what can be done with the ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually processing `request.POST` and `request.FILES` is *really* a bad idea: the data can be "forged", and the HTML specifications on how the request is constructed with a `<form>` have some peculiarities. For example if a checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="somename">` is *not* checked, then it does not appear in the request, whereas if it is checked, it appears with no value in the request.

A first problem is thus that not per se all fields of the form will appear in the `request.POST`, that is not per se a problem: some fields might not be required. The Django form will thus check for all fields that are required, if the value appears in `request.POST` and `request.FILES`.

Next the form will start *cleaning* the data. This means that it converts the data, which are all strings, to a more suitable datatype. For example for a `DateField`, it will try to convert this to a `date` object. It will normally try all formats in the [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats), but you can customize that when you construct a `DateField` to thus use a different format for that specific field. Some fields, like a `BooleanField` will for example look if the field is indeed in the `request.POST` and then return `True` and otherwise `False`, so this is not just a simple mapping of the value in `request.POST`, since that value might not be there.

Cleaning does not only map strings on corresponding Python objects, it can also do some (small) post-processing on these fields. For example a `CharField` will by default *trim* the string, and thus remove leading and trailing spaces, whereas a `ModelChoiceField` will pick the corresponding model object for that primary key from the database. A form field has also a list of *empty values*: values that are considered to be empty. For example for a `CharField`, you can set `'/'` as an empty value. It will then thus consider the slash as the field being empty.

One can create extra form fields than the ones that are defined, and this thus means that it is easy to construct for example an `EANField` where you implement the cleaning once, but that would mean that you need to do that for every view. Form fields are thus used to make cleaning more reusable by implementing the cleaning process into the field.

Next in line are validations on the form fields. While a text field in HTML can have a `<input type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="24">`, you can nevery rely on what the browser will post as values: indeed POST requests can be *forged*, so while the HTML form might intent to prevent people from picking a username with less than six characters, or more than twenty-four characters, you can not be sure that this will be the case in the POST request. A form field can be passed [**`validators=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#validators): a set of callables that raise a validation error in case the item is not valid. For example for a `CharField`, if you pass a value for the `min_length=…` and/or `max_length=…` validators, it will thus check these. It will add all `ValidationError`s to a list, which is often cumbersome to implement in a view: most views that validate data will check a certain condition, for example the minimum length of the characters for a password, and if that fails, report an error, whereas with a `Form`, it can also add an extra error that you should use at least one digit. The form will do that for all form fields, and thus construct a dictionary mapping the name of the fields to a list of errors.

If all the form fields successfully return validate the data, then the form will create an attribute [**`.cleaned_data`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) that maps the names of the fields to the corresponding value that has been cleaned by that form field. One can however further add additional cleaning and validation to the `Form`.

Then there are validations at the form level itself. If you want to slightly customize the form, then form a field named *`field_name`*, you can implement a `clean_field_name` method. This method can access the `.cleaned_data` dictionary, and then run additional validation on that field and raise a `ValidationError`, and furthermore "clean" the function, for example by returing an object of a different type, or doing some post-processing on the data that is then returned. The Form will thus collect these values and update the dictionary with these cleaned values. Furthermore if the method raises a `ValidationError`, the error will be added to the `.errors` for that specific field.

After that, the form will call the [**`.clean()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean). This will perform cleaning on the entire form. Indeed, now that all fields are cleaned individually, it might still be possible that there are errors about the *combination* of the fields. For example whether the two password fields match. Usually the `clean` method will thus work with *multiple* fields in the `.cleaned_data` attribute, and return for example that dictionary, or another object. If you raise a `ValidationError` here, the error will be put in the `.errors` under the `'__all__'` key, since this is not related to a specific field.

For a [**`ModelForm`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm), the validation is not over yet. Indeed, the model itself can still have some validation. It will update the instance wrapped in the form with the values of the cleaned data, and call the [**`.full_clean()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) on the instance, and later also call the [**`.validate_unique(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) to validate that for fields that should be unique (have `unique=True`), these are indeed unique. That last task is often more complicated than it looks at first sight, since if the instance is edited in the form, the check in the database, should *exclude* the current instance you are editing.

Only after all these validation, the `Form` or `ModelForm` will accept the change, and then `.is_valid()` will return `True`. If in one of the steps thus fails, the error will be added to the `.errors`, and thus `.errors` will try to construct a dictionary that tries to report all the problems with the data. This is useful if you *re-render* the form, since then the errors can be put next to the corresponding field, and the user thus gets feedback on *all* the problems with the data, not the first one encountered by the form, since that could result in a lot of attempts to eventually fix the form.

To summarize: there is a lot of logic in place in a `Form` to validate and clean data. Trying to implement that in a view is a popular mistake. It is cumbersome to do it correctly in a view, but it is also not very flexible: if you want to add an extra validator for a password for example, it will take a lot of work to implement that, especially if you want to that in multiple views. Forms are created to work with *reusable* components like form *fields*, *validators*, uniqness checks, etc. It is also quite robust since it is aimed to validate request data that might be *forged*, and thus was not validated properly by the HTML attributes.